# How to do if imports if multiple settings files

Tags: python, django

I have three settings files in a django project, so for example in my wsgi file I can do:

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'settings_staging')
```

But then my question is, how would I do imports **everywhere else** in the project? For example:

```
from settings import AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

This wouldn't be from "settings" anymore, but from "settings_staging".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't import the settings directly from your settings file, but load them via `django.conf.settings`. From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code):

> In your Django apps, use settings by importing the object `django.conf.settings`. Example:
>
> ```
> from django.conf import settings
>
> if settings.DEBUG:
>        # Do something
> ```

`django.conf.settings` will itself correctly load the settings file you want to use based on the settings module you specify in `wsgi.py`.

`manage.py` also looks for an environment variable specifying which settings module to use, so you can choose which settings module to use by setting the enviroment variable, e.g., :

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings_development
./manage.py runserver
```

Comment: When I use django runserver, I don't think it uses the wsgi file at all? It always just says `os.environ['environ'] == 'settings'`. Is there a way to change this from runserver?

Comment: I've edited the answer to explain how to control that.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Would an alternate approach be in the wsgi file to add in what `STAGE` it is in, for example: `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'settings')
os.environ.setdefault('STAGE', 'staging')` ?

Comment: No - you still need to set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`. That is what the [settings loader looks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/#designating-the-settings) for to decide where to load settings from. If you need to use another environment variable then you need to modify `wsgi.py` to still set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` based on your custom variable.

Comment: Of course -- I'm saying to include that always, but add on another variable to tell what settings to load. In this way you always load the same settings file -- see my answer below for what I mean by this.

Comment: Ah okay, I understand what you mean now. Yes, that approach is fine and commonly used!

Answer (score 1):

Another possible approach and the one I ended up doing is to have one settings file and then a `STAGE` where you can import more sensitive credentials. It looks like this:

```
# settings.py

# Part1 -- all my initial settings

# Part2 -- load in any sensitive variables
if STAGE == 'LOCAL':
    pass
elif STAGE == 'STAGING':
    from settings_staging import *
elif STAGE == 'PRODUCTION':
    from settings_production import *

# Part3 -- finish up loading settings, such as DB, CACHE, etc.
```

And in the wsgi file you can do something like:

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'settings')
os.environ.setdefault('STAGE', 'staging')
```

This way by just changing the `STAGE` environment -- whether it's wsgi, local, or anywhere else, you can have all the settings correct.